# Event for when a Button is held clicked for some time

Tags: wpf, button, click, repeatbutton

I am simulating a handheld device with WPF and MVVM (viewmodel is a state-machine, view is a simulated plastic case with buttons).

The gesture that turns the device on and off is a "long click" in a button. For exemple, during use, if I press "OK" button, it displays some screen, but if I HOLD it clicked for more than three seconds, it should (in a simulated way) turn the device off.

I took a look in `RepeatButton`, with its `Delay` and `Interval` properties, but those seem to fire the same `Click` event. What I need is to fire a regular `Click` if I hold the button for less than three seconds, and fire *another*, different `LongClick` (possibly once) if I hold it for more than three seconds.

How can I do this, using RepeatButton or even a regular Button?

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this would be to bind to the MouseDown and MouseUp events. Use something like a Stopwatch that gets started on MouseDown and check the amount of time that's elapsed on MouseUp. If it's less than 3 seconds, do your Click() action. If it's more than 3 seconds, do your LongClick() action.

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
}

private void Button_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch.Stop();

    if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 3000)
    {
         // do Click()
    }
    else
    {
        // do LongClick
    }
}
```

And here's a solution for RepeatButton:

```
private bool isLongClick;
private bool hasAlreadyLongClicked;
private void RepeatButton_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    isLongClick = false;
    hasAlreadyLongClicked = false;
    stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
}

private void RepeatButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!hasAlreadyLongClicked && stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 3000)
    {
        hasAlreadyLongClicked = true;
        isLongClick = true;
        // do your LongClick action
    }
}

private void RepeatButton_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isLongClick)
    {
        // do short click action
    }
}
```

The trick here is that a RepeatButton is basically just a Button that fires Click at every interval. So, if we start the Stopwatch on PreviewMouseDown for the button, we can check the elapsed time on the stopwatch every time the Click event fires, and modify our action based on the result.

Comment: The LongClick event should not wait until I relase the mouse, but actualy when three seconds have elapsed. But that would be an interesting (and simple, and effective) solution. Gonna give it a try.

Comment: @heltonbiker Hm. That's a lot closer to the function of the RepeatButton than the Button. I'll see if I can come up with something like that.

Comment: Yeah, my current widgets are repeatbuttons, since this is the hardware behavior they emulate. The core of my question would be "how to differentiate the first click from the subsequent ones?"

Comment: @heltonbiker Got it! Check out the second solution.

Comment: Your last code makes me believe that I will ALWAYS get a variable number of Click events before start getting LongClick ones?

Comment: @heltonbiker You'll get a click event every time the interval you set on the RepeatButton passes, yes. That's the way the Click event is implemented for the RepeatButton. You may want to set some boolean flags to make sure that the LongClick action is only performed once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64064/discussion-between-furkle-and-heltonbiker).

Answer (score 0):

After a weekend's meditation, I devised the following, working solution:

1. Create two boolean flags in ViewModel: `ClickedShort` and `ClickedLong`;
2. Binding the `Command` property on button, via commanding, to `OK` method on ViewModel;
3. The OK command is like this:

   ```
   public void OK()
   {
       if (!ClickedShort)
       {
           HandleShortClick();
           ClickedShort = true;
       }
       else if (!ClickedLong)
       {
           HandleLongClick();
           ClickedLong = true;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Have two CheckBoxes in XAML, with `IsChecked` properties bound to the boolean flags. These are just relays so that I can send information from View to ViewModel via binding:

   ```
       <CheckBox x:Name="ClickedShort" IsChecked="{Binding ClickedShort, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
       <CheckBox x:Name="ClickedLong" IsChecked="{Binding ClickedLong, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
   ```
5. Have a `MouseUp` event in OK button to reset those flags to false when I release the button.